# Keeping Rewrite but allowing hotlinking in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

Hiz
I have already asked this question few days back but havent received any answer yet.so i am going to delete that and re ask here.

I have this .htaccess rewrite rule which redirects/rewrites directly accessed images of a certain folder to its original page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?imgzzz.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule i/image_(\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) pic/$1 [L]
```

But it also stops the hotlinking. Can i modify this code that it wil let users hotlink the image but will send directly opened images to image page like the above code is doing ?

Already tried removing the first line. it stops the image to display on main pages.

and doing this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*$
RewriteRule i/image_(\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) pic/$1 [L]
```

If its not possible to keep the redirect to image page and allow hotlinking then is it possible to allow pinterest in my site to hotlink image so images can be submitted to pinterest.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule i/image_(\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) pic/$1 [L]
```

The **!^$** means not blank, so the image is being accessed via a page link, from any site:

Comment: Hello, by doing that image stops showing up on original image pages e.g  http://www.imgzzz.com/pic/1356988098

Comment: What appears in you /var/log/httpd/access*log  for the failed requests?

Comment: i am not sure about that i would have to ask my hosting guy to take a look at it